# heroku webapp displays error, says "Cannot GET /"

Tags: heroku, get, facebook-messenger-bot, messenger, facebook-webhooks

I have been following the webhook setup on Facebook Developer:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/webhook-setup

I have been deploying my index.js file on a heroku server and all it says is error, cannot get (reference link here)... [error on application server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcFii.png)

Other than my unique token I have not changed anything and in fact the heroku logs show that the events are being registered (reference link here)   [heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dInCy.png)

Would really appreciate some help on understanding how I can get rid of this error webpage so I can use this app link as my callback URL for messenger chatbot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a route pointing to '/' in your app

```
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
return response.send('Ping!');
});
```